# How do I set up an ethernet connection inside of a wifi network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I'm not a network expert and I can't seem to work this out:

-I have a home office setup with two laptops and a desktop in room 1. I have a network switch and ethernet for these three computers (mac and windows mix).
-In room 2 I have a wifi router. Each of the computers in room 1 are connected together to the wifi in room 2.
-How do I connect the laptops in room 1 together to make the most of the ethernet connection between them, but still have access to the wifi in room 2 ? The wifi is fast enough for our normal internet usage, but not fast enough for the demanding file transfers we're doing internally between our computers.

I've tried bridging connections between my adapters but not sure it's really working as I thought it would work..

any help would be very welcome!

Comment: Try Ethernet over Powerline to get Ethernet to room 2 and then set up from there.

Comment: Your description is confusing.  *"Each of the computers in room 1 are connected together to the wifi in room 2."*  -- Each computer would individually connect using WiFi.  When PC_1 accesses PC_2 using WiFi, there is no direct path, but rather with the wireless router (or WAP) in room_2 as a middle man relaying all the packets.  If you can afford the extra cost, then adding a wireless router (in client WAP mode) to room_1 would probably be the simplest solution IMO (e.g. each computer will have just one IP address & automatically use optimal network path).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to connect the three computers to the switch and configure static IP (from a private IP subnet that is different from the one the wifi network use) on each of them. Leave gateway and DNS blank, then they can reach each other with those addresses you assigned to them while using the WiFi for Internet at the same time.

Make sure you have the subnet mask / prefix length right. For example, if you decide to use `192.168.123.0/24`, make sure you set the subnet mask to `255.255.255.0`, or have the prefix length following the address (e.g. `192.168.123.1/24`) when configuring.